# Limiting Eloquent chunks

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a very large result set to process and so I'm using the `chunk()` method to reduce the memory footprint of the job. However, I only want to process a certain number of total results to prevent the job from running too long.

Currently I'm doing this, but it does not seem like an elegant solution:

```
$count = 0;
$max = 1000000;
$lists = Lists::whereReady(true);

$lists->chunk(1000, function (Collection $lists) use (&$count, $max) {
    if ($count >= $max)
        return;

    foreach ($lists as $list) {
        if ($count >= $max)
            break;

        $count++;

        // ...do stuff
    }
});
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: @whoan this doesn't work because `chunk` calls `forPage` which uses `take` which is a pseudonym for `limit`. As such, `chunk` overwrites anything you passed into `limit`.

Comment: I think a saw a take function for collection objects. sorry for useless input

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of right now, I don't believe so.

There have been some issues and pull requests submitted to have chunk respect previously set skip/limits, but Taylor has closed them as expected behavior that chunk overwrites these.

There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/103) in the laravel/internals repo where he said he'd take a look again, but I don't think it is high on the priority list. I doubt it is something he would work on, but may be more receptive to another pull request now.

Your solution looks fine, except for one thing. `chunk()` will end up reading your entire table, unless you return `false` from your closure. Currently, you are just returning `null`, so even though your "max" is set to 1000000, it will still read the entire table. If you `return false` from your closure when `$count >= $max`, `chunk()` will stop querying the database. It will cause `chunk()` to return false itself, but your example code doesn't care about the return of `chunk()` anyway, so that's okay.

---

Another option, assuming you're using sequential ids, would be to get the ending `id` and then add a where clause to your chunked query to get all the records with an `id` less than your max `id`. So, something like:

```
$max = 1000000;
$maxId = Lists::whereReady(true)->skip($max)->take(1)->value('id');

$lists = Lists::whereReady(true)->when($maxId, function($query) use ($maxId) {
    return $query->where('id', '<', $maxId);
});

$lists->chunk(1000, function (Collection $lists) {
    foreach ($lists as $list) {
        // ...do stuff
    }
});
```

Code is slightly cleaner, but it is still a hack, and requires one extra query (to get the max id).

Comment: That's a good tip about returning false. Are you also saying `chunk()` ignores my `whereReady` clause?

Comment: @eComEvo No, it does not ignore it. And that is one argument of those that would like to see it change, is that it ignores skip/limit (because it needs to use those itself), but it respects all other conditions set on the query. It is inconsistent.

Comment: @eComEvo I've also updated my answer with another option to consider. Just something else I thought of, but it is still another workaround.

Comment: that's an interesting idea, but since the id's will have gaps due to not all `Lists` being `ready` almost at random, I think this will produce inconsistent results.

Comment: @eComEvo That's why the query to get the max id also includes the `whereReady()` restriction (and will need to include any other where clauses, order bys, etc. that you will have on your main query).

Comment: @eComEvo But, these operations aren't atomic, so you do have a danger of one of the non-ready ids < $maxId being set to true in the middle of your chunking, meaning it will get processed by the chunk. Then you would end up processing $max + however many extra middles ids that became ready.

Comment: that's also true. I'll just stick with breaking the `foreach` then returning false when max is detected because I need it to be fairly precise. Appreciate the suggestion tho!

Comment: @eComEvo No problem. Also, instead of `break`ing the `foreach`, you could `return false;` there, as well. That will save you one extra chunk query when your `$max` is a multiple of your chunk size.